# Installing Zizaco entrust and confide

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, role

I am following the instruction of the link

---

https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

---

I have written `"zizaco/entrust": "dev-master"` in require section of composer.json and then update it on command prompt by the command `php composer.json update`.
I have also run the command `php composer.json dump-autoload`.
It gets updated.
I have added the provider and alias line in app.php and in Auth.php model and table is also set as 'users'.
But when I run the command `php artisan entrust:migration`
It shows me the error as follows

[image]

---

Please help me as I need to work on it fast.
Kindly let me know what and where is the problem.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: hopefully, you've also written `"zizaco/confide": "1.0.x"` in  your composer.json, as it is Confide that is missing here. Remember those are two packages. Install Confide first, then install Entrust.

Comment: Sir,I have written the same for confide also.
Now I have manually downloaded zip from the same link but still the same error.So kindly tell me the location where I need to paste the folder Zizaco.

Comment: Why do you download the zip file? Composer should do the job. It looks as if you simply hadn't installed Confide properly when you ran `php artisan confide:migration`.

Comment: Sir,When I update my composer at command prompt using command: `php composer.json upload` 
after adding `"zizaco/entrust": "dev-master",
  "zizaco/confide": "1.0.x"` in composer.json --------- still the files are not downloaded automatically.Kindly suggest me a solution.

Comment: If you want to help then please tell me the location of zizaco folder name with its location in laravel file structure. My problem would be resolved then.Thank You.

Comment: You sir, are a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: I am Thanking You for your help.
But my problem is still untouched.So finding another way to start it by manually downloading the files.

Comment: The problem is with your commands.  `composer` commands don't start with `php`.  May need to take another look at the manual for installing composer, then laravel, then entrust/confide.  At this stage, it would probably offer the most help to you.

Comment: I have tried first while executing command `composer update` then it shows me error 'config' is not recognised as an internal or external command.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where by each time I run 'composer update' the packages I needed where not included as I expected. So as my solution, each time I want to start a project in laravel 4, I first edit my composer.json file before running 'composer install'. Since then I do not have such embarrassment again.